# HibernateTools Reverse Engineering tool does not add Annotation for generator

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, reverse-engineering

I have my MySQL DB Schema created and I am using Hibernate Reverse Engineering file to create annotated Domain Object (.java). Though the file is generated correctly, it is somehow missing the "Generator" annotation for ID field.

Below is my hibernate.reveng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE
hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse
Engineering DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd"
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-name="products" match-catalog="test"></table-filter>
  <table catalog="test" name="products">
    <primary-key>
      <generator class="native"></generator>
      <key-column name="product_id"property="product_id" />
    </primary-key> 
  </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

and the generated class file (Products.java):

```
// default package
// Generated Jan 21, 2011 8:27:16 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Products generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", catalog = "test")
public class Products implements java.io.Serializable {

 private String productId;
 private String productName;

 public Products() {
 }

 public Products(String productId) {
  this.productId = productId;
 }

 public Products(String productId, String productName) {
  this.productId = productId;
  this.productName = productName;
 }

 @Id
 @Column(name = "product_id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
 public String getProductId() {
  return this.productId;
 }

 public void setProductId(String productId) {
  this.productId = productId;
 }

 @Column(name = "product_name", length = 200)
 public String getProductName() {
  return this.productName;
 }

 public void setProductName(String productName) {
  this.productName = productName;
 }

}
```

Is there something missing in my hibernate.reveng.xml file or hibernate does not generate annotation for "generator"?

Comment: After some searching, I followed some help and made following corrections: 1) Updated Product_Id db column data type to INT 2) Assigned AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. Now the tool is able to generate annotation for Native Generator like "@GeneratedValue" in Domain Object (Products.java). I still have to check whether this works only for INT columns or for columns with other data types too and how to make it work for VARCHAR columns.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check "ejb3" or add in the config:

```
<hbm2java  jdk5="true" ejb3="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <key-column name="product_id" property="product_id" />
```

There's a problem here. This part is correct: `key-column name="product_id"`, it maps to the DB column `product_id`, but this part is wrong: `property="product_id"`, this is the Java property and that is called `productId`, not `product_id`. This is the correct value:

```
  <key-column name="product_id" property="productId" />
```

And yes: AFAIK auto-generation is only possible for numeric types.